# Find the last value of a matching row above in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table of items that tracks the price over time. When I add a new row to the table, and the item name already exists within the table, I would like to retrieve the most recent "new price", and store it in the "prev price" column.

| Item | Date | Prev Price | New Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 2023/01/01 | 1 | 2 |
| banana | 2023/01/01 | 1 | 2 |
| apple | 2023/02/01 | 2 | 3 |
| banana | 2023/02/01 | 2 | 3 |
| apple | 2023/03/01 | 3 | 4 |
| banana | 2023/03/01 | 3 | 4 |
| apple | 2023/04/01 | (should pull 4) | 5 |

In the above example, when "apple" is entered into A8, it should look back and find "apple" at A6, then populate C8 with the value from D6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use XLOOKUP with search_mode=-1

```
=XLOOKUP(A8,A$2:A7,D$2:D7,,,-1)
```